# Boost Asio - boost::bind causes program to crash

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm having a problem when I try to compile my program with `boost::bind` as a parameter to an `async_read_some` function call.

If I use this code below, my program will crash when it reaches `async_read_some`.

```
socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(message_, 1024),
            boost::bind(
                &Session::print_message, self, 
                boost::asio::placeholders::error, 
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)
        );


void print_message(boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t length)
{
}
```

But if I remove `boost::bind` and replace it with a lambda function it will work just fine.

```
    socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(message_, 1024),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t length)
        {
            if (!ec)
            {
                std::cout << "made it" << std::endl;
            }

            std::cout << "Error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
        }
```

This is the error I'm receiving when I compile

```
'R boost::_mfi::mf2<R,Session,boost::system::error_code &,size_t>::operator ()(T *,A1,A2) const': cannot convert argument 2 from 'Arg1' to 'A1'
```

If anymore code is needed, please let me know.

Comment: you have not provided the declaration of `Session::print_message`

Comment: I have updated the post with the declaration.

Comment: Signature of handler is wrong, [see here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html),  - *signature of the handler **must be*** `void handler(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred);` , change to `print_message(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t length)`

Comment: @rafix07 Thanks, this solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rafix07 has pointed out, the program was crashing because I did not input the correct arguments for my `print_message` handler.

Needed to switch:

`void print_message(boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t length)`

to

`void print_message(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t length)`